# What's the difference between 意向　ｖｓ　意思?

Tags: meaning, nuances

I encountered this sample sentence:

> 佐藤さんは市長選挙に立候補する意向を固めたようだ。

The app I was using simply translated 意向 as "intention" which led me to ask: **how does it differ from 意思? And how do the component kanjis lead to this difference?** My first instinct was to recall other words that use the other kanjis. Words like 向こう、方向　and 思う、思想, but as I expected, using this strategy has a limit. (Btw, I'm thinking that 意向 is an intention that is externally manifested and that emphasizes a sense of direction, while 意思　is something internal and does not necessarily imply a set course of action.)

(Of course, I can look it up using a thesaurus, but I don't think it will strengthen my ability to intuitively grasp the fine shades of meaning, and will cause me to be too dependent on it.)

Comment: You seem almost answered your question yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I agree to what you thought from 漢字.
Plus, 意向 is usually other people's intention, not mine.
But anyway I think learning collocations is more practical way to master.
ご意向を伺う 意向に従う
意思決定 意思表示 意思無能力 etc